# Como evitar registro duplicados em um formulário php

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de exemplos de como fazer para evitar que o email seja duplicado caso algum usuário venha a tentar fazer cadastros múltiplos.

```
 <form action="processar.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="nome">
      <input type="email" name="email">
      <input type="submit">
   </form>
```

Processar.php

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "experiments";


//Pega os dados da form

   $nome = $_POST['nome'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];

 // Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection


$dupesql = "SELECT * FROM formulario where (email = '$email')";

$duperaw = mysql_query($dupesql);

if (mysql_num_rows($duberaw) > 0) {
   echo "Não deu certo, este e-mail já está cadastrado.";

} else {

$sql = "INSERT INTO formulario (nome, email)
VALUES ('$nome', '$email')";

}
```

Comment: Eu faria via ajax/jquery, assim que o usuário terminasse de digitar algo, faria uma consulta no servidor pelo email, se já existente, avisaria o usuário. Algo legal e liberar o submit apos todos os dados serem validados, html5o inputs, ajax/jquery, validação no back. Com ajax você evita mais trabalhos.

Comment: Recomendo usar mysqli ou PDO já que as funções mysql_* estão obsoletas.

Answer (score 1):

No select, ao invés de procurar por nome, você procura por e-mail.

```
$dupesql = "SELECT * FROM formulario where (email = '$email')";
```

Você pode complementar isso tornando o email chave primária no banco banco de dados. Dessa forma, mesmo que o usuário tente, não vai conseguir cadastrar um e-mail duplicado no seu banco.

Comment: Está ocorrendo o erro: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in na linha 23. :/

Comment: O restante do fluxo permanece igual. Você só altera essa linha que eu postei.
Atribui a execução do mysql_query  para uma variável e passa como parâmetro para o mysql_num_rows().

Comment: Este erro esta ocorrendo na linha do query... aquele "where" esta em letra minuscula... altera ele para letra maiuscula.. talvez de certo...

Comment: Continua ocorrendo o mesmo erro mesmo após alterar a where para maiúsculo.

Comment: Tem que olhar o log de erro ou exibir o erro com mysql_error() para ver o que é. Aconselho migrar para mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

Você ta criando a conexão com `mysqli_connect` e executando com `mysql_query`, repare a falta do `i`. Tente mudar, se mesmo assim der erro, modifique sua consulta para:

```
$dupesql = "SELECT * FROM formulario where email='$email'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu retiraria os parênteses depois do where:

As variáveis estão diferentes. Você usa `$duperaw` e `$duberaw`.

Confira já com as mudanças:

```
$dupesql = "SELECT email FROM formulario where email = '$email'";

$duperaw = mysql_query($dupesql);

if (mysql_num_rows($duperaw) > 0) {
//mensagem de erro //
}

else {
// continui //
}
```